# Postfix not accepting mail to virtual users

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I've setup some virtual users for certain domains. I've got a local domain (and plan to add some virtual mailboxes but I'll save that for later).

`localhost postfix/smtpd[23466]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from somedomain.com[173.xxx.198.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <user@domaina.com>: Relay access denied; from=<bounce@somedomain.com> to=<user@domaina.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<somedomain.com>`

I've been over these settings. Each time I've adjusted `/etc/postfix/valiases` I've run `postmap valiases`. I've then run `postfix reload` (and `/etc/init.d/postfix restart` to be sure).

My main.cf (substituting domain.com in):

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 109.123.86.72/32
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Linux)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vdomains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/valiases
```

/etc/postfix/vdomains

```
domaina.com
domainb.com
```

/etc/postfix/valiases

```
hello@domain.com        account@gmail.com # works
@domainb.com            account@gmail.com # doesn't work
user@domaina.com        other@gmail.com   # doesn't work
user2@domaina.com       another@gmail.com # doesn't work
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put something on the right hand side here:
/etc/postfix/vdomains

like

```
domaina.com x
domainb.com x
```

as Postfix uses it as a lookup table, so it needs some dummy value in the right hand side.
Or you can directly list it in main.cf instead of the lookup table.

Comment: Ah, if I remove the hash: prefix, can I go with my current vdomains file?

Comment: I inlined the domains and it now works: `virtual_alias_domains = domaina.com, domainb.com, domainc.com`. Adding x on each line so it can parse a hash didn't work after I reloaded postfix, unless I was supposed to run `postmap vdomains`? Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the delay. Yes you supposed to run postmap as it is an indexed file (hash). Inlining is fine.